# Etymology of Sicilian "amuninni"

Tags: regional, etymology

What is the etymology of the Sicilian expression "amuninni" / "amunì"?
I am assuming that the -nni suffix corresponds to Italian -ne as in "andarsene".
Is "amunì" a 2. plural imperative of a verb (annari?) If it is, which verb?

Comment: Ho trovato i seguenti riferimenti, non so quanto affidabili: “*L'esortazione "Amunì" usata dai siciliani e in modo particolare dai palermitani letteralmente vuol dire Andiamo.
La dottoressa Teresita Da Roca y Capell di Barcellona asserisce che AMUNI' deriva dal catalano della zona di Lleyda-Agramunt, dove si usa ancora amùnt, che si pronuncia amunì, nel senso esatto di andiamo.*”

Comment: “*L' insigne grecista G. Cosentini, ragusano, afferma invece che Amunì deriva dal verbo greco àmino (scritto amuno) che significa ‘tenersi lontano, spostarsi da un luogo’, per cui il nostro esortativo imperativo, diviene àmune, ma noi, che accentiamo sempre l’ultima sillaba ed evitiamo le e sostituite dalla i, per iotacismo, arriviamo subito ad amunì.*”
(Dizionario sentimentale della parlata siciliana G.Basile) https://it-it.facebook.com/109686135728500/photos/amunilesortazione-amun%C3%AC-usata-dai-siciliani-e-in-modo-particolare-dai-palermitan/2262344893795936/

Comment: @Hachi: A Lleida, a Agramunt, a Barcellona e ovunque "amunt" è un avverbio che ha un uso simile all'avverbio italiano "su" (indica "verso l'alto") e non si pronuncia in questo modo da nessuna parte (io lo pronuncio [ə'mun̪], a Lleida credo si pronunci [a'mun̪]). E chi sarebbe questa "Teresita Roca i Capell" che soltanto con questo nome fa quasi ridere?

Comment: @Charo - https://www.darioflaccovio.it/index.php?controller=attachment&id_attachment=249 - pagina 16

Comment: @Hachi:   Dubito dell'esistenza di qualcuno che si chiami "Da Roca y Capell" che sembra una strana mescolanza di italiano-catalano-castigliano. In catalano, si ha l'abitudine di separare il primo cognome e il secondo cognome con la congiunzione "i" ([esempio](https://ca.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miquel_Mart%C3%AD_i_Pol)), ma "y" è la congiunzione castigliana equivalente, che non si usa con i cognomi nel castigliano odierno. Poi il diminutivo castigliano "Teresita" fa anche sorridere ("Teresa" però è un nome catalano e ha anche diminutivi catalani): nessuno si farebbe chiamare dott.sa Teresita ...

Comment: In rete si trovano tracce di una “Teresita Daroca Capell”, che però sarebbe una nutrizionista...

Comment: C'è anche una [Teresita Daroca Capell](http://renati.sunedu.gob.pe/handle/sunedu/1381543) che sembra peruviana o, perlomeno, ha qualcosa a che vedere con il Perù. Secondo la mia esperienza, che qualcuno si faccia chiamare Teresita in Perù è più frequente. E, a dire il vero, c'è ancora qualcuno a cui piace separare i due cognomi in castigliano con la "y", ma non è mai ufficiale.

Comment: Mentre Gaetano C. Cosentini sembra esistere veramente: https://www.buonenotiziedallasicilia.tv/classici-nella-modernita-legame-la-sicilia-intervista-al-prof-gaetano-cosentini/

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about the etymology of "amuninni" / "amunì", but I can tell you that they are the plural [exhortative](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/esortativo/) of the verb "iri".

I found [this page](https://digilander.libero.it/dawngate/dia_irregolari.html) with conjugations of some Sicilian irregular verbs, where there is no imperative nor exhortative, and the page of the [Sicilian Wikipedia](https://scn.wiktionary.org/wiki/jiri) for the verb jiri/giri/ghiri/iri where there is the plural imperative "jemu". However there is no exhortative, I am afraid you have just to believe me.
Googling "amunì esortativo" I found [this piece of art](https://mauamuseum.com/works/amuni-ca-scuro/) in which description you can find a reference to the exhortative purpose of of the expression.

Don't bother too much about the different spellings.
In Sicily each city has it's own slightly different version of Sicilian.
For example people from where I come from would use indiscriminately **iri**/**jiri** (I think they are pronunced in the same way) or **ghiri**, but never **giri**.
And they would say "nantri emu" or at most "nantri iemu", instead of the Palermitan "nuatri iamu" which you find in the link to the irregular verbs.

Comment: Siccome si è tirato in ballo il catalano, in questa lingua questo esortativo è *anem* o *anem-nos-en* (significa "andiamocene"). In registro colloquiale spesso  si dice *'nem*.

Comment: The Catalan expressions "anem" / "anem-nos-en" are similar to the Sicilian ones and since Sicily has been under Spanish domination from 1500 to 1700 it's possible that the etymology of "amunì" is to be tracked down in the Catalan language.

Comment: In fact it was under the [Crown of Aragon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crown_of_Aragon) (that is, not exactly "Spain") that Catalan was spoken in Sicily.